# Why isn't my LibGDX project seeing the Overlap2DStage class from the Overlap2D runtime, even though I've added it as a Gradle dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I'm following along with [this tutorial for using Overlap2D with LibGDX](http://overlap2d.com/making-physics-based-side-scroller-project-setup-part-1/). As part of the tutorial, I'm adding the [Overlap2D runtime](https://github.com/UnderwaterApps/overlap2d-runtime-libgdx) to my dependencies in Gradle. Following [the instructions on the runtime's website](https://github.com/UnderwaterApps/overlap2d-runtime-libgdx#setting-up), which say

> If you are using gradle, yo can just add this line to your dependecies:

```
compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

I've added the following to my `build.gradle`:

```
// snip...

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    }
}

//snip...
```

In my LibGDX project, there are multiple autogenerated `build.gradle` files. I've made this change to the `build.gradle` file in the root of the project.

Then, directly copying code from the tutorial I'm following, I try to use the Overlap2D runtime library in one of my classes:

```
import com.uwsoft.editor.renderer.Overlap2DStage;

public class GameStage extends Overlap2DStage {  
}
```

Compiling this class fails:

```
GameStage.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class GameStage extends Overlap2DStage {
                               ^
  symbol: class Overlap2DStage
```

Why can't my project see the classes from my Gradle dependency? Have I not added the dependency to my project correctly?

I'm using NetBeans, but compiling the project fails from the command line too, so I don't believe my IDE is the cause of the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I was following is out of date. The `Overlap2DStage` class I was trying to use [is no longer a part of the Overlap2D library at all](http://overlap2d.com/forums/topic/new-runtime-help/#post-2404)!

If you were following that tutorial as well, Overlap2D now has a video tutorial that is more up to date here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhvHm2sM0qo&feature=youtu.be

Follow the video tutorial instead.